# ActiveRecord: выборка последних пяти записей

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

У меня такая проблема, я только началa изучать RoR.

У меня есть данные в базе данных (блог Name, Title, Content). Мне нужно выбрать последние 5 записей, как это реализовать? Что писать и куда? В контроллер? Что именно писать?

Это вид домашней страницы, вторая ссылка должна переходить на страницу с выбранными пяти записями

```
<div id="head"><h2 align="center">Музыкальный блог musicasfreedom</h2>
<p id="come">
 <%= link_to "Войти", posts_path %>
 <br>
 <%= link_to "Показать пять последних",posts_path(@index1)%>

def index1
@index1 = Post.limit(5)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

 def index
@posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

Сейчас у меня по обеим ссылкам выводятся ВСЕ записи ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно ссылаться на разные методы контроллера, для этого пропишите ваш index1 в routes.rb.

Выполните
    rake routes

и вы увидите список всех доступных методов.

А вообще почитайте что-нибудь вроде [этого](http://russian.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning) учебника, думаю вы сейчас просто не понимаете принципов работы RoR.

Comment: а что именно мне написать в routes.rb
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :olas
  resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end

 get "home/index"
 root :to => "home#index"

Comment: вам нужно прописать туда маршрут (route) который будет связан с методом какого-то контроллера. Говорю ж, почитайте учебники сначала, иначе напишите кучу плохого кода, кусок которого вы уже предоставили.

Comment: спасибо, получилось!спасибо, что подсказали с маршрутизацией!

Answer (score 1):

Такой вопрос уже был - [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420352/how-to-get-last-n-records-with-activerecord)

Если вкратце, то вам чтобы получить последние 5 записей нужно написать

```
Post.last(5).reverse
```

Это вернет последние 5 постов, причем самый новый будет первым, код этот должен быть в каком-нибудь action контроллера понятное дело(каждый public метод контроллера это action). И далее во вьюшке выводите данные в записях.

Меня еще смутило в вашем коде, что залогиниться в ваш блог вы даете ссылку на блоги -

```
<%= link_to "Войти", posts_path %>
```

Это довольго странно.

Comment: у вопрощающего проблема не в пяти последних, а в рельсах в целом :)